# Struggling with JS Array Lengths

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this piece of code, when you look at it it would seem that the logic should run as follows:

I create 3 empty arrays, I add one value to bankSelectedData, I print out the values, obviously bankSelectedData is now 1 and bankSelectionArrayCurrent length is 0, but then I say:

```
bankSelectionArrayPrevious = bankSelectionArrayCurrent;
```

So I'm turning bankSelectionArrayPrevious into bankSelectionArrayCurrent. When I check the size of bankSelectionArrayPrevious is says '1' ?? How is this possible?

```
var bankSelectionArrayCurrent = new Array();
var bankSelectionArrayPrevious = new Array();
var bankSelectedData = new Array();
    bankSelectedData.push("value1");

alert("bankSelectionArrayCurrent length: "+bankSelectionArrayCurrent.length);
alert("bankSelectedData length: "+bankSelectedData.length);

if(bankSelectedData.length != bankSelectionArrayCurrent.length){
    bankSelectionArrayPrevious = bankSelectionArrayCurrent;
    bankSelectionArrayCurrent.length = 0

    alert("previousSize: "+bankSelectedData.length);
    alert("currentSize: "+bankSelectionArrayCurrent.length);
}​
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Ahh I'm such an idiot!.. Thanks guys..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you have

```
alert("previousSize: "+bankSelectedData.length);
```

perhaps you meant:

```
alert("previousSize: "+bankSelectionArrayPrevious.length);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code never changes "bankSelectedData", so its length remains 1 after you add that first value.

Your code does not contain any `alert()` call with the length of "bankSelectionArrayPrevious".

Answer (score 2):

Your alert is wrong.  It should be:

```
alert("previousSize: "+bankSelectionArrayPrevious.length);
```